# Contract Table Query Exception

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, table, eosiocpp

As i was following eosio developers documentation

```
    #include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/print.hpp>

using namespace eosio;
using namespace std;

class addressbook : public contract {

public:
  using contract::contract;

  addressbook(account_name self): contract(self) {}

  [[eosio::action]]
  void upsert(account_name user,  string first_name,  string last_name,  string street,  string city,  string state) {
    require_auth( user );
    address_index addresses(_self, _self);
    auto iterator = addresses.find( user );
    if( iterator == addresses.end() )
    {
      addresses.emplace(user, [&]( auto& row ) {
       row.key = user;
       row.first_name = first_name;
       row.last_name = last_name;
       row.street = street;
       row.city = city;
       row.state = state;
      });
    }
    else {

      addresses.modify(iterator, user, [&]( auto& row ) {
        row.key = user;
        row.first_name = first_name;
        row.last_name = last_name;
        row.street = street;
        row.city = city;
        row.state = state;
      });
    }
  }

  [[eosio::action]]
  void erase(account_name user){
    // require_auth(user);
    address_index addresses(_self, _self);
    auto iterator = addresses.find( user );
    eosio_assert(iterator != addresses.end(), "Record does not exist");
    addresses.erase(iterator);
  }

private:
  struct [[eosio::table]] person {
    account_name key;
     string first_name;
    string last_name;
     string street;
    string city;
     string state;
    uint64_t primary_key() const { return key; }
  };
  typedef eosio::multi_index<N(people), person> address_index;

};

EOSIO_ABI( addressbook, (upsert)(erase) )
```

after executing following command ,I got

```
cleos get table addressbook addressbook person -k alice

     Error 3060003: Contract Table Query Exception
Most likely, the given table doesn't exist in the blockchain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typedef eosio::multi_index<N(people), person> address_index;
```

Check that the name of table you are providing N(people), but you are executing

```
cleos get table addressbook addressbook person -k alice
```

you should be executing

```
cleos get table addressbook addressbook people -k alice
```

If you find any issue check the abi file generated for debugging.